# error 'No NFC device found' al momento de ejecutar nfc-list

Tags: raspberry-pi, librería, nfc

He instalado libnfc1.8.0 en una raspberry pi con el S.O Bullseye de la siguiente forma:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev libpcsclite-dev i2c-tools
cd libnfc-1.8.0
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
make
sudo make install
cd /etc
sudo mkdir nfc
sudo nano /etc/nfc/libnfc.conf
```

Y luego ingreso este texto en el archivo libnfc.conf

```
[Escribir lo siguiente en el archivo:]
# Allow device auto-detection (default: true)
# Note: if this auto-detection is disabled, user has to set manually a device
# configuration using file or environment variable
allow_autoscan = true

# Allow intrusive auto-detection (default: false)
# Warning: intrusive auto-detection can seriously disturb other devices
# This option is not recommended, user should prefer to add manually his device.
allow_intrusive_scan = false

# Set log level (default: error)
# Valid log levels are (in order of verbosity): 0 (none), 1 (error), 2 (info), 3 (debug)
# Note: if you compiled with --enable-debug option, the default log level is "debug"
log_level = 1

# Manually set default device (no default)
# To set a default device, you must set both name and connstring for your device
# Note: if autoscan is enabled, default device will be the first device available in device list.
device.name = "_PN532_SPI"
device.connstring = "pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0:500000"
#device.name = "_PN532_I2c"
#device.connstring = "pn532_i2c:/dev/i2c-1"
```

Hasta ahí la instalación ha salido bien, pero al momento de ingresar el comando **nfc-list** o **nfc-poll**

Me marca esta advertencia:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.8.0
No NFC device found.
```

¿Alguien sabe que es lo que sucede, si me falto instalar alguna otra cosa?

Estoy 100% seguro que el Reader que estoy utilizando esta funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta a esta pregunta es muy sencilla, sucede que la manera en que estaba instalando la librería no era la adecuada. Aún no estoy 100% seguro sobre si es que me faltaba un paso para lograr que me detectara el **Reader** pero encontré una forma más sencilla de instalar libnfc1.8.0.

Pasos para realizar en la terminal:

1. `sudo apt install libnfc6 libnfc-bin libnfc-examples`
   Al ejecutarlo nos aparecerá la siguiente pantalla
   [image: Y y enter]
   Ingresaremos **Y** y le damos **Enter**
2. `sudo nano /etc/nfc/libnfc.conf`
3. Ahora en el archivo que se nos abrió ingresamos estas dos lineas al final

```
device.name = "Itead_PN532_SPI"
device.connstring = "pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0:100000"
```

Nos quedaria algo tal que así
[image: Configuración]

4. Ya por último damos **Ctrl+O** y **Enter** para guardar el archivo y **Ctrl+X** para salirnos de editar el archivo.

Ya solo bastaría ejecutar el **nfc-list** y se detectaria correctamente el Reader que tengamos conectado.